# express js sendfile and download in react client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have express js as backend and react js as front end , in some route I have to send a file in response to requests I've done it like this :

```
return res.status(200).sendFile(path.resolve(`files/${product.fileName}`))
```

and the thing I have propblem with is that how should i handle this response in reactjs client ?
I loged the response and the body is :

```
body : ReadableStream 
       locked : true
```

Comment: I have searched stack overflow and found nothing , but if its a duplicated question plz tell me to remove it

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the send utility of express like this?

```
 var fs = require('fs-extra'); // import fs-extra package
 var buffer = fs.readFileSync(req.query.filepath);
 var bufferBase64 = new Buffer(buffer);
 res.status(200).send(bufferBase64);
```

In the React client, you can use react-file-download package.

```
import fileDownload from 'react-file-download';
fileDownload(response.data, "profilepic.jpg"); //This will download the file in browser.
```